# How to UPDATE Multiple table using Postgresql & Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have data in the form of array and i want them to be updated into multiple table. Im using Codeigniter and Postgresql

**Here is my controller**

```
public function update()
{
    $where = array(
        'id' => $this->input->post('id')
    );

    $data = array(
        'case_name' => $this->input->post('txtCaseName'),
        'firm_name' => $this->input->post('txtFirmName'),
        'case_description' => $this->input->post('txtCaseOverview'),
        'service_names' => $this->input->post('txtDesiredServices'),
        'instruction' => $this->input->post('txtinstruction'),
    );

    //print_r($data);
    //die;

    $this->HomeModel->update($data, $where);
```

**This is my Model:**

```
var $table = array('tracker.case_main,
    tracker.case_overview,
    tracker.type_of_services,
    tracker.instructions');
//(tracker is my scheme name)

public function update($data, $where)
{   
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Error im receiving :

> Error Number: 42601/7
>   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Array"
>   LINE 1: UPDATE Array SET "case_name" = 'Mary Garner', "firm_name" =...
>                  ^
>
> UPDATE Array SET "case_id" = 'Medidoco_001sa', "case_name" = 'Mary Garner', "firm_name" = 'xyz', "case_description" = '', "service_names" = '', "instruction" = '', WHERE "id" = '78'
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/casetrackings/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

im new to php and codeigniter :P

Comment: You're defining `$table` as an array (which contains one single string) but are using it as a string in your `update()` method. Define it as a string instead: `$table = 'tracker.case_min, tracker.....';'`

Comment: Don't use the old PHP 4 way of adding class properties (using `var`). You can [read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) about the recommended way.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson  Thnx a lot for helping me.. i solved the problem and i am able to update all the table well and good..